# Avoid FetchContent when conan has already downloaded targets from package

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, conan, conan-2

I have included a test application which tests the main project using gtest. I want these tests to be executable in both cases, using cmake alone or conan with cmake. So I defined a dependency on gtest in conanfile as follows:

*conanfile.py*

```
..
def requirements(self):
    self.test_requires("gtest/1.14.0")
..
```

As I want the app to also be testable when NOT using conan, I included a call to FetchContent in the tests CMakeLists.txt.

*tests/CMakeLists.txt*

```
## Dependencies

..
# googletest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG v1.14.x
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES GTest
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
..
```

As you can see I defined FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES GTest so that CMake should check if a target with this name exists before it downloads the gtest git repo. However, it turns out the download is always performed, even when I'm building my project with conan. My initial thought was that conan would download the gtest package and export the targets, so that a subsequent build of the project would settle for the already found target instead of fetching the whole thing again. Why is it not working and how can I account for this case?

Comment: Using FetchContent and Conan to retrieve the dependencies are alternatives, but they cannot be used simultaneously. The easiest would be to protect the ``FetchContent`` calls with an ``if(NOT CONAN)`` or something like that, and inject the variable in the ``conanfile.py`` via ``CMakeToolchain`` in the ``generate()`` method, so it is passed only when building with Conan

Comment: "... CMake should check if a target with this name exists ..." - No, this is not what passing `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` option means. The meaning of that option in your case is that CMake calls `find_package(googletest NAMES GTest)`, and, if that call succeeds, CMake skips downloading and building the googletest. If your integration with Conan is based on a toolchain file, which provides path to the GTest config file, then the above `find_package` call would succeed. Note, that call `find_package(googletest NAMES GTest)` won't use `FindGTest.cmake`, unlike to the usual `find_package(GTest)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes that's what I thought would happen. In fact conan does provide a toolchain file, moreover it provides the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH option over command line which should search the installed libs for config files. Why isn't it detected?

Comment: @drodri But for succesful configuration in cmake the project actually needs all targets from all dependencies, how come the dependency of gtest is not found? Am I not understanding the mechanics correctly?

Comment: What if you insert `find_package(googletest NAMES GTest REQUIRED)` before the `FetchContent_Declare`, would it succeed when build with Conan?

Comment: Yes, the ``find_package`` must exist for Conan to find it and create the targets. That could also be protected by the same variable.